# How to add the settings Icon to the custom keyboard on Android under settings-> language and Input

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I have created a custom keyboard on android, but I am unable to add a settings icon next to the custom keyboard name under settings->language and input.

Is there an xml file where I can add the settings gear icon or should it be part of the input method service